# Visual Studio Class Diagram Custom Collection Association

Tags: c#, visual-studio, diagram, visual-studio-extensions, class-diagram

Consider the following hypothetical data classes:

```
public class Comment
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Topic
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public SourceList<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

The `Topic` class exposes a `SourceList` of type `Comment`. `SourceList` is a type defined in the [`DynamicData` library](https://dynamic-data.org/). The thing is that this class doesn't expose its items on its surface, meaning that the items are exposed through an `IEnumerable` property named `Items`. Hence, the Visual Studio class diagram fails to find the association:

[image: VS class diagram error when choosing Show as Collection Association]

Is there any way to extend VS class diagram functionality to support such custom collection implementations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did some research but didn’t find any way to meet your requirement. I think the existing [extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=diagram&target=VS&category=All%20categories&vsVersion=&sortBy=Relevance) maybe also don’t work.

Comment: @Tianyu Thanks for your time. Yeah, the thing that surprises me is that the VS modules usually have a means of extensibility, which I can't find for the class diagram.